# Spring CORS fails ONLY on some resources

Tags: java, spring, rest, google-chrome, cors

I have a RESTful web-service with a lot of different resources (endpoints) all of which work perfectly fine when invoked from Postman. However, **only some of them** work from the browser, while the rest of them fail. I can't spot any pattern whatsoever in the URLs that fail vs. the URLs that don't fail.

I am invoking the resource directly from Chrome console.

For example, this is the resource that fails from browser, but works from Postman - **/api/hello/**.

```
fetch("https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/hello/", {method: "GET", headers: {"authToken" : "7c577770c0b7f1b2ba0f7dbb10ae247978a9997cf8aec3bbab0ac7de409e0b4c"}})
.then(res => res.json())  
.then(console.log)
```

For example, this is the resource that works from both Postman and Chrome.

```
fetch("https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/user/all/", {method: "GET", headers: {"authToken" : "7c577770c0b7f1b2ba0f7dbb10ae247978a9997cf8aec3bbab0ac7de409e0b4c"}})
.then(res => res.json())  
.then(console.log)
```

For the resource that failed, Chrome logged the following error.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/hello/' from origin 'http://admin.myapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I have observed that the exact same message appears if I try to fetch the resource that actually doesn't exist on my service, for example calling **/api/blabla/** results in exactly the same error.

My CORS configuration in Spring is as follows.

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String DEFAULT_ORIGIN = "https://admin.myapp.com";

    private static final Set<String> allowedOrigins = new HashSet<>();
    static {
        allowedOrigins.add(DEFAULT_ORIGIN);
        allowedOrigins.add("http://admin.myapp.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        final String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");

        if (origin != null && allowedOrigins.contains(origin)) {
            // set origin to our specific domain to disallow request from other sites
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        } else {
            // set origin to our default allowed
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", DEFAULT_ORIGIN);
        }

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", String.format("%s, %s", "Content-Type", HEADER_AUTH_TOKEN));

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
```

I can see the response headers being perfectly set on any call from Postman, and for the calls from Chrome that don't report an error. However, on the calls from Chrome that do report an error, the Access-Control-Allowed-Methods only contains GET.

TL;DR - I have no idea why CORS calls from browser fail only for some resources, while for the other resources it works fine.

Comment: The error cited indicates the server’s logging the message *“Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.”* So when that happens, inspect the request in the Network pane of browser devtools & check the HTTP status code of the response. The info you have in the question so far indicates that for the CORS preflight OPTIONS request to `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/hello/`, the server isn’t responding with a 200 OK as needed, so the preflight fails. You need to make the server respond to OPTIONS requests to that route with a 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

Spring handles CORS [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) requests automatically.

But you're not really using [Spring's CORS functionality](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors), so you should handle OPTIONS requests by returning HTTP 200 OK.

Something like this:

```
    if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

(Although I don't think this is the root cause of your issue)